# Set daemon to start at boot with systemd

Tags: systemd, daemon, init.d, sysvinit, start-stop-daemon

I'm writing a daemon to manage my Java app on a headless **Ubuntu 16.04** box using jsvc and [this (probably pre-systemd) tutorial](http://www.neilson.co.za/creating-a-java-daemon-system-service-for-debian-using-apache-commons-jsvc/), and got as far as running `update-rc.d mydaemon enable`, receiving the error

`update-rc.d: error: mydaemon Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting`

Having Googled around a bit this appears to have something to do with the (fairly?) recent move to `systemd`, which I have confirmed is running with `pidof systemd`.

How do I achieve the same starting-at-boot behaviour as `update-rc.d` (and more importantly *stopping* the service via `/etc/init.d/mydaemon stop` rather than just killing the process as the Java app needs to clean up). And are `systemd` and `update-rc.d` different systems, or does `systemd` just change how the latter works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a Ubuntu 16.04 to test this on, or provide you with many details, but systemd has a compatibility feature to allow older `/etc/init.d` scripts to continue working. Instead of using `update-rc.d` to enable your daemon, use the systemd native command equivalent:

```
sudo systemctl enable mydaemon
```

If this still produces the same error, add the missing lines to the starting set of comments in your script:

```
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
```

between the `### BEGIN INIT INFO` and `### END INIT INFO` lines, and try again.
See the [LSB core](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html) description for these lines. 
You can also explicitly start the daemon with

```
sudo systemctl start mydaemon
```

and ask for its status with

```
sudo systemctl status -l mydaemon
```

See `man systemd-sysv-generator` for the compatibility feature. See [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) for converting System V or upstart scripts like yours to native systemd Units.

Comment: Ah thank you. I'd inadvertantly done this as I'd made a new systemd script in /usr/systemd but still came up with these errors. I figured since the systemd script _referenced_ the systemv one, that's why it was causing the errors and so I added these lines in the systemv script. Didn't realise systemd was automatically converting systemv scripts into systemd ones.

Comment: see https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Answer (score 0):

You must have a /etc/init.d/tightvncserver script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tightvncserver
# Should-Start:      
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs x11-common
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: VNC server
# Description:       Debian init script for the VNC Server
### END INIT INFO
# /etc/init.d/tightvncserver

# Set the VNCUSER variable to the name of the user to start tightvncserver under
VNCUSER='pi'
case "$1" in
  start)
    su $VNCUSER -c '/usr/bin/tightvncserver :1 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 16'
    echo "Starting TightVNC server for $VNCUSER"
    ;;
  stop)
    pkill Xtightvnc
    echo "Tightvncserver stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/tightvncserver {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

and then run the command:

```
sudo service tightvncserver start
```